wire:navigate mobile experience lag between navigations
I'm considering rebuilding one of my web applications in the TALL stack and utilising Livewire's full page components support to get that SPA feel. I've observed that when adding wire:navigate on links, on a desktop there's not much of an issue, since the prefetching links strategy works quite well.
My concern though is over the mobile experience. What strategies can be done to rectify the lag between clicking a link that has wire:navigate and ending up on the destination page since on mobile, a user cannot hover.
Even if some kind of caching strategy, or "warm-up" strategy whereby once a link has been visited it then is faster for page navigations for users thereafter?
